# java : Returning stream or resulting bytes

Tags: java, java-io

I have need to return the byte array for the `ByteArrayOutputStream` from the called method.  I see two ways to achieve the same thing: firstly to return `ByteArrayOutputStream` & use `toByteArray()` method, and secondly use `baos.toByteArray()` and return the byte array.

Which one should I use?

To illustrate by example:

**Method 1**

```
void parentMethod(){
        bytes [] result = process();
    }
    void byte[] process(){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
        .....
        .....
        .....
        baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

**Method 2**

```
void parentMethod(){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = process();     
    }
    void ByteArrayOutputStream process(){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
        .....
        .....
        .....
        return baos;
    }
```

Comment: Given that `parentMethod()` doesn't need to concern itself with how it got the bytes, returning the `byte[]` seems better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's another alternative: return an `InputStream`. The idea is presumably that you're returning the data resulting from the operation. As such, returning an *output* stream seems very odd to me. To return data, you'd normally either return the raw `byte[]`, or an `InputStream` wrapping it - the latter is more flexible in that it could be reading from a file or something similar, but does require the caller to close the stream afterwards.

It partly depends on what callers want to do with the data, too - there are some operations which are easier to perform if you've already got a stream; there are others which are easier with a byte array. I'd let that influence the decision quite a lot.

If you *do* want to return a stream, that's easy:

```
return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

So to summarize:

- Don't return `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The use of that class in coming up with the data is an implementation detail, and it's not really the logical result of the operation.
- Consider returning an `InputStream` if callers are likely to find that easier to use or if you may later want to read the data from a file (or network connection, or whatever); `ByteArrayInputStream` is suitable in the current implementation